# Get control ids from table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where email Inbox is shown in it (please see excerpt ss [here](http://snag.gy/03qSs.jpg)).
When user clicks on checkbox, I should populate 2 dropdowns with proper items.

```
function fnHandleSelectCBClick(cb) {
    try {
        var tableRow = $(cb).parent().parent();
        // Here I should be able to find control ids of other 2 dropdown in the table row.
        // Tried below code and failed
        //var propSelect = $(cb).parent().parents('tr:first').find('select');
        //var taskSelect = $(cb).parent().parents('tr:second').find('select');
    } catch (e) {alert(e);}
}
```

[Here](http://snag.gy/a5Pf6.jpg) is the table row structure screenshot.
If I can get their ids, I can directly fill items and then later it can validated too.
I am a beginner javascript and jQuery. Please correct if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Why dont you use your tableRow? Like `tableRow.find("select")`. `.first()` for first, `.last()` for second (would be better to use class names, so you could do `tableRow.find("select.property")`).

Comment: If fnHandleSelectCBClick is the event handler, cb is an event object, not a jquery dom object, so instead of $(cb) you should use $(cb.target) (so better if you rename it to e, evt or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown the full html for table and button, so you may need to adjust this based on id's, class names etc.

```
$('#YourTableID').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var selects = row.find('select');
  var first = selects.first(); // this is the first select
  var second = selects.last(); // this is your second select
});
```